# Wordpress, get ID's of multiple categories from the URL

Tags: wordpress, categories

I'm using WordPress 2.8.4.

My question is, if I'm viewing a sub category (`cat-slug-2` in this example) is there a built in function to get it's *category ID* and its *parents category ID*?

Here's an example URL, where `cat-slug-2` is a sub category of `cat-slug-1`

`http://www.foo.com/category/cat-slug-1/cat-slug-2/`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
<?php
    $current_category = single_cat_title("", false);
    $category_ID = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT term_id FROM $wpdb->terms WHERE slug = '" . $current_category . "'" );
    echo(get_category_parents($category_ID, TRUE, ' &raquo; '));
?>
```

For more info on the WP Functions/Template Tags used above, see [single_cat_title](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/single_cat_title) and [get_category_parents](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_parents).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer Manzabar, from your code i was able to modify it to get what i wanted.

Ultimately, I wanted an array of the category's parentIDs. Here's how I did it:

```
$parents = get_category_parents($cat, false, '^%%^');
$parents = explode('^%%^', $parents);
$parentIDs = array();
foreach($parents as $parent){
    if (is_null($parent) || empty($parent)){
        continue;
    }
    $parentIDs[] = get_cat_ID($parent);
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($parentIDs);
echo '</pre>';
```

Note that $cat holds the **current** categoryID